# For what does clojure implement implicit conversion between, e.g. a vector to a list?

Tags: clojure

If I do

> user => (next [1 2 3])

I get

> (2 3)

It seems that an implicit conversion between vector and list is being operated.

Conceptually, applying `next` on a vector does not make a lot of sense because a vector is not a sequence. Indeed Clojure does not implement `next` for a vector. When I apply `next` on a vector, Clojure kindly suggests that "You wanted to say (next seq), right?".

Isn't it more straight forward to say that a vector does not have `next` method? What can be reasons why this implicit conversion is more advantageous and/or necessary?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the docs, next says:

> Returns a seq of the items after the first. Calls seq on its argument.
>   If there are no more items, returns nil.

meaning that this method calls seq on the collection you give it (in your case, its a vector), and it returns a seq containing the rest.

In clojure, lots of things are "colls", such as sequences, vectors, sets and even maps, so for example, this would also work:

```
(next {:a 1 :b 2}) ; returns ([:b 2])
```

so the behavior is consistent - transform any collection of items into a seq. This is very common in clojure, map and partition for example do the same thing:

```
(map inc [1 2 3]) ; returns (2 3 4)
(partition 2 [1 2 3 4]) ; returns ((1 2)(3 4))
```

this is useful for two main reasons (more are welcome!):

1. it allows these core functions to operate on any data type you throw at them, as long as it is a "collection"
2. it allows for lazy computation, eg. even if try to map a large vector but you only asked for the first few items, map wont have to actually pre-compute all items.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure has the concept of a sequence (which just happens to display the same as a list.

next is a function that makes sense on any collection that is a sequence (or can reasonably be coerced into one).

```
(type '(1 2 3))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentList

(type (rest [1 2 3])) 
=>clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq
```

Comment: Ok. Firstly Clojure does not implicitly convert a vector to a list. I did (type (1 2 3))` with Clojure 1.5.1. It gave me clojure.lang.Cons. I am not yet understanding these Cons and Chunked***

Comment: cons is how lisp's build their lists, you should read [about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons), chunked is a clojure optimization of cons that helps lazy-seqs run faster (by each time evaluating an entire chunk rather than the next cons-cell).

Answer (score 1):

There are tradeoffs in the design of any language or library.  Allowing the same operation to work on different collection types makes it easier to write many programs.  You often don't have to worry about differences between lists and vectors if you don't want to worry about them.  If you decide you want to use one sequence type rather than another, you might be able to leave all of the rest of the code as it was.  This is all implicit in Shlomi's answer, which also points out an advantage involving laziness.

There are disadvantages to Clojure's strategy, too.  Clojure's flexible operations on collections mean that Clojure might not tell you that you have mistakenly used a collection type that you didn't intend.  Other languages lack Clojure's flexibility, but might help you catch certain kinds of bugs more quickly.  Some statically typed languages, such as Standard ML, for example, take this to an extreme--which is a good thing for certain purposes, but bad for others.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure lets you control performance / abstractions operating a choice between list and vector.

List

- is fast on operations at the beginning of the sequence like `cons` / `conj`
- is fast on iteration with `first` / `rest`

Vector

- is fast on operations at the end of the sequence like `pop` / `peek`
- participates in associative abstraction with indexes as keys
- is fast on `subvec`

Both participate in sequence abstraction. Clojure functions and conversions they operate, are made to ease idiomatic code writing.